# Standard Bolt Pattern for Racks in Datacenters

Tags: hardware, datacenter, rack

Is there a "standard" way of bolting racks down that is interchangeable between vendors?

At our datacenter we've standardized on a Damac rack for our builds. Because we're building in volume, the colo provider works ahead to bold down our racks (raised floor, all-thread into concrete below and anchored to the floor tiles as well). This is in zone 4 earthquake area.

We've auditioned a competing rack from Rittal and found that it doesn't attach to the pre-drilled holes w/o a custom bracket.

Is there a standard for holes to bolt racks down or does everyone do it their own slightly different way?

Comment: A bit naïve but perhaps adding a short deck between the floor and the cabinets to allow free adaption to any cabinet would be of benefit.  I would guess that raised floor systems and typical datacenter design guidelines make that a bit more prohibitive

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sadly every rack provider is different depending on how they are assembled.  If you switch you'll be either be replacing floor tiles or you'll have extra holes in the floor which need to be covered/plugged.